# get current time as PT08H10M00S

Tags: javascript, datetime, odata

how can i convert current time in format as PT08H10M00S. I use an Odata service for communication and which expects time in format as PT08H10M00S which is 8:10:00 in time. Is there any inbuild js function to do the same.

Comment: It looks like a timespan, not time.

Comment: What is `PT`  here?? Is it static or dynamic?

Answer (score 1):

If PT is dynamic then you can add code to derive at runtime how ever you want

```
var d = new Date();
var customDate= 'PT'+ d.getHours()+'H'+d.getMinutes()+'M'+d.getSeconds()+'S';
console.log(customDate);
```